# text overlay for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

How to add an instructional text overlay for .net c# textbox?

I want to get the same effect as the title textbox on this page:

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Try [AJAX : TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax TextBox Watermark control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE2" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="TextBox1"
        WatermarkText="Type First Name Here"
        WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
```

You can get it from [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Comment: @Downvoter- Downvoting dosen't makes sense leave comments before downvoting

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) to do that:

sample:

```
$('#inputId').watermark('watermark you want to show');
```

Or you can use javascript:

```
function watermark(inputId,text){
  var inputBox = document.getElementById(inputId);
    if (inputBox.value.length > 0){
      if (inputBox.value == text)
        inputBox.value = '';
    }
    else
      inputBox.value = text;
}

<input id="inputTextboxId" type="text" value="type here" onfocus="watermark('inputTextboxId','type here');" onblur="watermark('inputTextboxId','type here');" />
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'watermark' I get when trying the above.

Comment: did you include the plugin file in your project and reference in your page?

Comment: In your master page head or page head add this <script src="Scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>... and in Script folder add js file from site above

Comment: That did the trick, but the text is the same colour as the normal text that is input into the box. How can I for example make it a lighter gray?

Answer (score 1):

If you use asp.net you can use TextBoxWatermarkExtender from the Ajax-Control-Kit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

---

It is an extender, not a replacement for the textbox, use it like this:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtSalesEventNo" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="30%" />
<act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wmSalesEventNo" TargetControlID="txtSalesEventNo" WatermarkText="Sales Event Number" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked_border" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This would be ok but it does not handle many attributes of a standard textbox, such as Rows, Width, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this [solution](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/419900-como-fazer-um-overlay-no-jquery/)

```
/* Full overlay */
$(function () {
    $('.full_overlay .content').hide();
    $('.full_overlay').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('.content').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.content').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
    })
});
```